# Obtain departure and arrival dates from acoustic telemetry dataset

Tags: r

I have an acoustic telemetry data set obtained from tracking the seasonal movement of several stingrays between an MPA and an estuary. Among the columns, I have one with the timestamps of each detection (datetime), the name of the stingrays it corresponded to (ind), and whether the detection occurred in the MPA or in the estuary (area).

I have been trying (with no success) to create a new data frame just with the departure and arrival dates from and to the MPA, that is, the last date in which each individual was detected before being detected in the estuary, and viceversa, the date each stingray was detected for the first time after returning (i.e., after being detected for the last time in the estuary).
I would also like to add a column with the date of last detection in the previous place and a column with the time differential between both, to have an idea of the time it took them to travel between both areas.

The code looks like this

```
datetime             ind        area

2019-04-02 08:54:03  Animal_1   mpa
2019-04-02 09:01:13  Animal_2   mpa
2019-04-02 15:45:22  Animal_1   mpa
2019-04-03 17:31:50  Animal_1   mpa
2019-04-03 21:24:38  Animal_1   estuary
2019-04-04 00:01:24  Animal_1   estuary
2019-04-04 00:01:24  Animal_1   estuary
2019-04-05 03:32:56  Animal_1   estuary
2019-04-05 18:42:07  Animal_2   estuary
2019-04-05 18:49:23  Animal_2   estuary
2019-04-06 17:16:24  Animal_1   mpa
2021-04-06 12:34:56  Animal_1   mpa
2021-04-06 16:05:50  Animal_2   estuary
2021-04-06 22:29:37  Animal_2   mpa
```